# integration of $ \frac{1}{\ln(A \sqrt x + B)}$

Tags: integration

I try to find solution for that: $$\int\frac{1}{\ln(A\sqrt  x + B)}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. I don't mind to make some assumptions or expend it, but it doesn't work with Taylor expansion. 
Many thanks! 
shai

Comment: Please use Mathjax to help us better understand your question. There is a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Start changing variable $A \sqrt x+B=e^t$ which gives $x=\frac{\left(e^t-B\right)^2}{A^2}$, $dx=\frac{2 e^t \left(e^t-B\right)}{A^2}dt$; you then have $$I=\int \frac{dx}{\ln(A \sqrt  x + B)}=-\frac 2 {A^2}\int\frac{ e^t \left(e^t-B\right)}{t}dt=\frac 2 {A^2}\Big(\text{Ei}(2 t)-B \,\text{Ei}(t)\Big)$$  where appears the  exponential  integral function.

The required function has the following series expansion $$\text{Ei}(z)=\gamma+\log (|z|)+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k \, k!}$$

Comment: Ah thank you very much....!

Comment: You are very welcome ! It was a very interesting integral.